# how to make a basic app.yaml file for a nodejs Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am making a nodejs project for google app engine. Testing is all fine and the app is functional, but when prompted to deploy my code files via `gcloud app deploy`, I am given the following error:

> ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy
>   this directory as an App Engine application

I have never used yaml before. What should the contents of a basic yaml file look like to fix this problem and deploy my code?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html, YAML's basic is simple as as follows:

> Dictionary - `key: value`
>
> ---
>
> List/Array (1) -
>  
>   `name:
>     - item1
>     - item2`
>
> ---
>
> List/Array (2) - `name: ["item1", "item2"]`
>
> ---
>
> Nested Properties (1) - 
>   `nest:
>     nestedKey: value
>     nestedList:
>       - item1
>       - item2`

Regarding the specific YAML file you specified, read up on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml for more information.
Here's a simple example from that page:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Answer (score 2):

For node your current options are `nodejs10` and `nodejs12`:

> Accepted runtimes are: [php, php55, python27, java, java7, java8,
> go111, go112, go113, go114, java11, nodejs10, nodejs12, php72, php73,
> php74, python37, python38, ruby25]

So an example `app.yaml` file, using a node server and the standard environment, would be:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12
env: standard

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Note that some versions may have additional requirements eg:

> script field for handler '/.*' must be set to 'auto' for runtime nodejs12.